# Recover accidentally deleted directory

Tags: hard-drive, software-recommendation, data-recovery

In the process of backing up my audiobooks, I "permanently" removed a folder (with subfolders) that I had already exclusively moved to that drive. It's path is /media/gratis/Seagate Expansion Drive/Audiobooks/Jason Dark . The sole folder in that should be called John Sinclair; but I'm not sure about that.

Which tool offers the best chances to recover those files. I hadn't written plenty on that drive afterwards; so I hope for the best.

It's not that other methods failed; I just cant get my head around what to do and I want to be cautious. It's a NTFS Drive.

According to testdisk it has an "EFI GPT" Partition table.

```
Disk /dev/sdb - 5000 GB / 4657 GiB - CHS 608001 255 63, sector size=512 - Seagate Expansion Desk, FW:9401
```

Information According to "Disks" (Ubuntu Standard Software):

```
NTFS; GUID Partition Table; [...] Partition Type: Microsoft Reserved
```

Comment: What kind of file system is on the drive?

Comment: @Andrea Lazzarotto:

According to testdisk it has an "EFI GPT" Partition table.

Disk /dev/sdb - 5000 GB / 4657 GiB - CHS 608001 255 63, sector size=512 - Seagate Expansion Desk, FW:9401

Comment: OK, the geometry information is good to know. You may consider [edit]ing your question to include it. However the main question remains: what file system is on the drive? NTFS, FAT, EXT4? Please clarify.

Comment: @David Foerster:

Hi, it's NTFS. That answers your question, doesn't it? I should have made that clearer after the first edit.

Comment: @David Foerster: Thanks!
ntfsprogs seems to no longer be in repos; but already installed on my machine so no problems there.

I always get the error: Access is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
You can use force option to avoid this check, but this is not recommended
and may lead to data corruption."

Although I only just plugged it in and even quit Nautilus by force (nautilus -q)

I ran sudo ntfsundelete /dev/sdb2 -f

Comment: @DavidFoerster: That gave me a list of a bunch of files, 205013 to be exact. Now, what I want is the content of the directory .../Audiobooks/Jason\ Dark/ to be restored. What do I have to do?

It's .m4b & .opus files and folders, of course.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: Yep - https://askubuntu.com/questions/921989/how-to-specifically-use-ntfsundelete-to-recover-directory